# Sorting table with associated columns rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting

I'm trying to sort table with associated columns, so user can sort songs by song name, artist, album, genre and length. But I'm not sure how to do it. 
as it is now I can only sort songs by their name.

**UPDATE**

So the first column is working. But I can't sort with the rest of the columns, they only can revert to 'asc' or 'dsc' If I clicked on the song name to sort them. Hope I'm making sense?

Here is my code below:

**SongsController**

```
def index
    @songs = Song.order("#{sort_column} #{sort_direction}").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
    @latest_albums = Album.order('created_at DESC').last(5)
end

    private

  def sortable_columns
    ["name", "length", "artist", "album", "genre"]
  end

  def sort_column
    sortable_columns.include?(params[:column]) ? params[:column] : "name"
  end

  def sort_direction
    %w[asc desc].include?(params[:direction]) ? params[:direction] : "desc" 
  end
end
```

**SongHelper**

```
def sort_link(column, title = nil) 
    title ||= column.titleize
    direction = column == sort_column && sort_direction == "asc" ? "desc" : "asc"
    icon = sort_direction == "asc" ? "fa fa-angle-double-up" : "  fa fa-angle-double-down"
    icon = column = sort_column ? icon : ""
    link_to "#{title}<span class='#{icon}'></span>".html_safe, {column: column, direction: direction}
  end
```

**View**

```
   <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th width="10%"></th>
        <th><%= sort_link "name", "Song" %></th>
        <th><%= sort_link "artist_id", "Artist" %></th>
        <th><%= sort_link "album_id" %></th>
        <th><%= sort_link "length" %></th>
        <th><%= sort_link "genre_id" %></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Tell us what particularly is not working in code or how is it behaving. Looking at the all code wouldn't help anyone to figure out where the problem is.

Comment: Hey @kiddorails, well as it is now I can only sort songs by their name. So the first column is working. But I can't sort with the rest of the columns, they only can revert to 'asc' or 'dsc' If I clicked on the song name to sort them. Hope I'm making sense?

Comment: Show the rails server log for the request when you click any sort_link. First step to debug is to check what params are being sent in request.

Comment: Is this what you mean?  

Started GET "/songs?column=++fa+fa-angle-double-down&direction=asc" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-10-24 22:38:16 +0200
   (0.7ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
Processing by SongsController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"column"=>"  fa fa-angle-double-down", "direction"=>"asc"}

this is what happens when I click on the song name sort_link

Comment: Can you spot now what is wrong? Your value of column is being passed wrong. - fa-fa-angle-double-down. Your Rails logic checks of column being passed in a specific set, if not it uses name column

Comment: I added the answer. As a rule of thumb, I always recommend to check server log to understand what is happening in a request lifecycle. Things like parameters, routing errors, database queries are easily debugged when one begin to understand it.

Comment: Thanks @kiddorails, this works now! Thanks for the great advice too!

Comment: Great. I also added that as answer. If it fixed your issue, you can accept it as answer .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
 icon = column = sort_column ? icon : ""
```

to

```
icon = column == sort_column ? icon : ""
```

You need to check if `column` is equal to `sort_column`, whereas, your original code is *equating* column to `sort_column`